# The ship heeled or tilted or inclined?

Tags: phrases

The ship 'heeled' or 'tilted' or 'incline' in strong wind and sank.
Which word is correct and most common?

Comment: It's expected that a certain amount of research is shown alongside questions, on ELU.

Comment: I would say the boat heeled in the wind, then capsized (or keeled over) and sank.

Comment: While you're at it, you might want to take a look at the past-tense verbs _hove_ and _yawed_, too. So many interactions of boat and wind...

Comment: 'I will, thank you for reminding! –  Jokaec 22 hours ago'

Answer (score 5):

I would have said ***listed*** was the correct nautical term. *She listed to starboard and sank in 20 minutes*.

Comment: If she took a torpedo that would be correct.

Comment: listing is only due to excess weight in the wrong place, or indeed damage to the bottom of the boat

Comment: Like [this](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2895837/Car-transporter-cargo-ship-runs-aground-Isle-Wight.html)

Comment: @Joe Blow. Perhaps you can find a nautical glossary giving such a narrow definition. But you are ignoring the broader, more common sense given by say AHDEL. I would not dream of insisting '_similar_ only refers to shapes interconvertable under similarity transformations' on ELU (though that's the 'strict' mathematical definition).

Comment: Hmm - I fully agree with you that there are technical arcane usages and general usages.  A great point.  But listed and heeled are very "nautical terms". In that case, the user should simply say "leaned". In your analogy, it would be like "a civilian" bumbling with the word tensor or vector or such, instead of just saying "a line" or whatever they meant.

Answer (score 5):

Sailors have all sorts of specialized terms, and your example does not provide enough information. But it is clear that "inclined" is not the word to use.

Most likely, "The ship was hit by high wind, capsized and sank." is the preferred term. But let me expand (I love to lecture).

In general, a ship which tilts to the side (lengthwise tilt is pitch) is said to either heel or list. The difference is not entirely simple.

A list is a long-term tilt, and almost certainly indicates that the ship is in trouble. It usually occurs because either a) one or more compartments within the hull have flooded, or b) the contents, usually cargo, of the ship have shifted to one side. Neither of these is good, but neither is necessarily fatal.

Heel is most commonly used as a verb, and usually indicates a transient response to forces on the ship. Sailing ships heel to different angles depending on their orientation to the wind and the strength of the wind.

There are two major exceptions to the above. A heel can persist for a long time. For instance, a sailing ship can maintain a certain degree of heel for a very long time if it maintains a course at a fixed angle to the wind for a long time. Heeling can also be inadvertent, and can occur in both sailing and steamships, particularly when unexpected wind gusts hit the ship.

If the change in angle is particularly dramatic or unexpected, the ship can be said to "heel over", but not necessarily "keel over". "Keel over" can be used if the ship capsizes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsizing which means that it has tilted 90 degrees or more. If a small sailing ship ends up with its masts in the water it is said to have been knocked down.

So in your case the ship was hit by wind, heeled over, capsized and sank. If it was a small boat, it was knocked over and sank, but small boats don't usually sink when this happens, or at least not immediately. There exists a fuzzy line here - ocean racing yachts are an exception.

Yet another possibility exists. The ship was struck by wind, heeled over, and the cargo shifted and punctured the hull and the boat sank. This doesn't happen often, but it did happen to wooden warships in severe storms; the term "loose cannon" arose from these situations. In this case, it is not necessary for the ship to capsize, although in such a storm this is likely. So it is possible that the ship was struck by a wind gust, heeled over, the cargo shifted and the ship began to list. Water began to flood the hull, the list increased, and eventually the ship capsized and sank. Or the hull flooded and the ship sank without capsizing.

Answer (score 4):

"Heeled" is the correct nautical term.

Answer (score -1):

More commonly, "tilted" is used in speaking, but "heeled" is the correct term, in nautical form.

Answer (score -1):

[These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ship+heeled%2C+ship+tilted%2C+ship+inclined%2Cship+keeled%2Cship+listed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cship%20heeled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cship%20tilted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cship%20inclined%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cship%20keeled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cship%20listed%3B%2Cc0) seem to show that the frequencies of usage are in the order:

[(f)]*heeled* > *listed* > *tilted* > *keeled* > *inclined*.

(Though this is raw data; some may normally require an 'over'.)

Comment: But isn't there an actual difference between the meaning of *heeled* and *listed*? A properly loaded sailing ship in good repair will [heel](http://www.seatalk.info/cgi-bin/nautical-marine-sailing-dictionary/db.cgi?db=db&view_records=1&uid=default&Term=heel&submit=Look+it+up%21) but not [list](http://www.seatalk.info/cgi-bin/nautical-marine-sailing-dictionary/db.cgi?db=db&view_records=1&uid=default&Term=list&submit=Look+it+up%21).

Comment: AHDEL: **heel 2** 
_intr. & tr.v._ 
To tilt or cause to tilt to one side. _n_.
A tilt, as of a boat, to one side. // **list 3**  n.
An inclination to one side, as of a ship; a tilt.
intr. & tr.v. 
To lean or cause to lean to the side >> Or are we now NLU?

Comment: A sailboat is supposed to *heel* in a strong wind. But a sailboat only *lists* if it's damaged or the load isn't balanced.

Comment: Are you saying that AHDEL's definitions are inadequate? Nautical terminology is doubtless prescriptive. But surely general English usage is more relevant on ELU. Google reports '133,000 results' for "heeled over and sank".

Comment: That would depend on what the OP wants to use the word for. But if you look at the picture in the online AHDEL under *heel*, it shows a sailboat heeling the way it's supposed to, and if you look at the example usage in AHDEL under *list*, it's *the damaged ship listed badly to starboard.* If you know something about boats, you won't confuse them. If you don't, then using them incorrectly shows your ignorance.

Comment: Finally, let me say that *heeled over and sank* is different from *heeled and sank*, and I would imagine perfectly acceptable nautical terminology. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keeled+over+and+sank%2Cheeled+over+and+sank%2Clisted+and+sank%2Cheeled+and+sank&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckeeled%20over%20and%20sank%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheeled%20over%20and%20sank%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clisted%20and%20sank%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheeled%20and%20sank%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: My understanding is that "heel" refers to leaning caused by dynamic forces on the vessel, whereas "list" refers to leaning caused by a static imbalance.

Comment: (I doubt that Ngram is a good judge of nautical terminology.)

Comment: @PeterShor But I didn't get the impression the OP was talking about a sailing boat responding to wind. A 'ship' - which eventually sinks - is mentioned! I was reminded of this, which happened only in January: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2895837/Car-transporter-cargo-ship-runs-aground-Isle-Wight.html

Comment: @Peter Shor If you are unbiased enough to include the definition accompanying the picture AHDEL provides (_heel_: (n) 'A tilt, as of a boat, to one side' and (v) To tilt or cause to tilt to one side) you will have to concede that general usage allows for (1) other applications than just nautical situations and thus (2) situations where a subsequent topple etc may result. Demanding a particular subject-specific usage is against accepted rules of interpretation. This echoes the difference between the more narrow scientific and the popular usages of 'hurricane'. Neither may be termed 'incorrect'.

Answer (score -1):

Both *heeled* and *listed* are nautical terms, but neither is really appropriate here.

From the [SeaTalk Nautical Dictionary](http://www.seatalk.info).

> **heel:** to lean or tip under the influence of the wind on sails. Heeling is a normal characteristic of any sailing vessel, and is controlled by the ballast and underwater design of the boat.
>
> **list:** to lean to one side because of improper loading or damage to the hull.

So *heeled* isn't quite right, because tilting over so much that the ship sinks is not normal for most sailing vessels.

And *listed* isn't right, either; the ship tilted over because of an excessively strong wind, and not improper loading or damage.

I'd suggest *keeled over* or *heeled over*. If you look at [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heeled+over+and+sank%2Ckeeled+over+and+sank%2Clisted+and+sank%2Cheeled+and+sank%2Cinclined+and+sank%2Ctilted+and+sank&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheeled%20over%20and%20sank%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckeeled%20over%20and%20sank%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clisted%20and%20sank%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheeled%20and%20sank%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctilted%20and%20sank%3B%2Cc0), *heeled over and sank* or *keeled over and sank* are much more common than *heeled/listed/tilted/inclined and sank*.

From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keel_over):

> **keel over**: Of a vessel: to roll so far on its side that it cannot recover; to capsize or turn turtle.

Comment: My so-so nautical knowledge tells me you're reading those a bit too literally.  A boat may *heel*, eg, due to making a sharp turn.

Comment: Both _heeled_ and _listed_ are also used with less strict definitions by many not au fait with the nautical register (which is less appropriate on ELU).

Comment: @Hot Licks: I agree; the SeaTalk Nautical Dictionary defines *heel* a little too specifically here.

Comment: "Heeled over" refers to something any sailboat does in a strong wind.  "Keeled over" refers to turning turtle.  I've been on a sailboat in both situations and I can tell you that they are two entirely different things.

Comment: @Hot Licks: that's what I thought, too. But Ngrams shows that "*heeled over and sank*" was the most common expression before around 1980, when *"keeled over and sank"* replaced it.

Comment: How is Ngram a judge of nautical terminology?

Comment: @Hot Licks: You can find a [report](https://books.google.com/books?id=xpxmAAAAMAAJ&q=%22heeled+over+and+sank%22+navy+report&dq=%22heeled+over+and+sank%22+navy+report&hl=en&sa=X&ei=A3lzVYWKKoulsAW1tYGICg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA) published by the U.S. Naval Academy in 1985 that contains *"The sixteenth and seventeenth centuries are replete with reports of warships that suddenly heeled over and sank, even in protected harbors."* I would expect them to know proper nautical terminology.

Comment: @PeterShor - "Suddenly heeled over" implies a dynamic event.  Warships of that era were notoriously top-heavy and were apt to capsize when maneuvering in tight quarters.

Answer (score -1):

Understand that "heeled over" means essentially the same as "heeled" -- the "over" just implies a bit more extreme situation.  And for a sailboat to be "heeled over" is not an unusual or worrisome thing -- it happens when the wind blows against the sails.  A boat (sailboat or motorboat) may also "heel" when making a sharp turn.

"Keeled over" means that the boat (which may or may not be a sailboat) has rolled over sufficiently that it's keel is exposed.  In general, unless we're talking about a kayak, this is not a good thing, and the boat will sink unless it contains sufficient floatation material to keep it afloat.

If a boat has "heeled over and sunk" it's because it either faced abnormally strong winds or was ineptly piloted.  In theory I suppose this could happen to a power boat that was foolishly put through a very sharp turn at high speed, but it would usually only happen to a sailboat.  (It would be unusual for an ordinary power boat to "heel" sufficiently in the wind to sink, outside of a major hurricane.)

Pretty much any boat (that is capable of sinking) can "keel over and sink", and this might be what happens if it's struck by a torpedo.

So, eg, Ngram (when it's actually scanning literate commentary) will tend to catch sailboats with "heel over" and power boats with "keel over".  At most one can judge, from the relative frequency of the two terms, the popularity in the literature of sailboats vs power boats.

**Update:**  I thought it might help the OP understand the scenario a bit better if I were to relate my experience with "heeled over" to the point of "keeled over".  This was about 1980, and I was sailing my 16-foot "daysailer" (standard triangular main and jib) single-handed on Lake Pepin.

I'd been out for several hours, in a decent wind (ie, I was "heeling" most of the time), and was beating upwind toward the launch area when it came time to tack.  As I was sailing single-handed (and I was tired) I had the jib cleated, even though this is "not advised".

My mistake was forgetting to un-cleat the jib before tacking.  This caused the back corner of the jib to be held in place by the mast stay rather than flopping over to the other side as it normally would.  The jib was suddenly a fairly large parachute, trying to pull the boat around and also push it over.

I figured out later that the way to recover from this was to let go of the tiller and let the jib pull the boat all the way around, to a jibe.  But in my inexperience I tried instead to steer upwind, which only succeeded in holding the sail at a right angle to the wind, the rudder being so small compared to that jib.

Playing it back in my mind after all these years it took maybe 5 seconds for the boat to heel over to the point of capsize.  Of course, since there was floatation foam under the seats, the boat did not sink, but rather "turtled" -- completely upside down, with the centerboard sticking straight up.

It took about an hour to figure out how to get the boat righted, but that's another story.  I am thankful, though, for another boat that stopped to help.

Comment: Hi Hot Licks.  It's utterly pointless you commenting here since, it would appear you have at one point in your life actually seen a boat.   You should be aware that the point of this page is for many people who do not know what a boat is to quickly read about "boat" on "wikipedia", and supply answers based on that.

Comment: actually i withdrew my up vote on the "pointless" basis  :O