# When a car on the edge of a cliff slides toward the precipice shortly and then stops, can we say that it "heels"?

Tags: phrase-usage

The car stopped and started to heel (to bend).

Comment: In that situation, 'to topple' would be idiomatic.

Comment: I would say "listing" rather than "heeling".  Only a sailboat "heels", but any boat can "list".

Comment: Perhaps you could explain in more detail exactly what the car did. Did it drive towards the precipice but stop before it got there? Did it go partly over the edge and hang there? Did it fall off? Did it stop at all?

Comment: @chasly from UK It shortly skewed in direction of precipice and freezed.

Comment: Do you mean like in these pictures? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=teeter&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMIlOLR5q_exwIVp6HbCh3xZgFi&biw=1481&bih=696#tbm=isch&q=car%20teetering

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Like this one http://www.worcesternews.co.uk/resources/images/3943952/

Comment: 'a car on the edge of a cliff slides toward the precipice shortly and then stops' is at odds with 'the car stopped and started to heel'.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I agree with OED that any *boat* can "heel". But not cars. Perhaps you're conflating *heel* with *keel* (I'm not nautical, but I'm guessing only sailboats would normally need *keels*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm just going on my experience of having owned a sailboat for about 25 years.

Comment: I'd say that car (in worcesternews) is about "this close" to tipping onto its side.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Ah. Well googling [**"Costa Concordia" heeled**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22Costa+Concordia%22+%22heeled%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) gets a *lot* of hits. And Google Books has a couple of [**he heeled over backwards**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+heeled+over+backwards%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) together with dozens of [**he keeled over backwards**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+keeled+over+backwards%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which suggests to me at least *some* people conflate the words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - There actually was a [thread on this several months back](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250836/the-ship-heeled-or-tilted-or-inclined).  Technically, "heeled" applies to a tilt due to *dynamic* conditions (either wind or a sharp turn), while "listed" applies to a tilt caused by *static* conditions (such as an unbalanced load).  "Heeling" can only occur with a boat that's moving, except in those rare cases where the wind blows over an anchored boat.

Comment: @Hot Licks: That makes sense - by which I mean the *static/dynamic cause* and *moving/stationary vessel* distinction(s) accord with what I know of common usage, though I wasn't consciously aware of either until now. But this/these distinctions are very fine, and unlikely to be consistently observed in all contexts. Particularly, *figurative* ones - so I don't think I would axiomatically assume the difference between a *listing drunkard* and a *heeling drunkard* was that the former was just drunkenly unsteady on his feet, but the latter must have been *pushed*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'd tend to think of a *heeling* drunkard as rolling forwards and back -- "rolling on his heels".  This of course would only vaguely relate to the nautical term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb is to **teeter**.  (But see my comment below in response to a comment)

Try [Google Images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=teeter&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMIlOLR5q_exwIVp6HbCh3xZgFi&biw=1481&bih=696#tbm=isch&q=car%20teetering) for  'car teetering' and you will see many pictures.

This is a bent car/vehicle.

[image]

This is a boat heeling

[image]

and this is a bus teetering on the edge of a precipice.

[image]

> **teeter**
>
> to ​appear to be about to ​fall while ​moving or ​standing:
>
> [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/teeter)

EDIT in response to a comment from the OP

The verb is *'to tilt'*.

*The car tilted.*

or

*The car tilted over.*

Comment: Not exactly. Teetering is "to and fro" motion. The car "leans" slowly towards the precipice.

Comment: @АнтонЕршов - So you disagree with the dictionary? 'While moving or **standing**' And you disagree with all the people who posted those pictures of cars under the caption 'car teetering'?  Note that a 'teeter-totter' is specific to the USA. You can't generalise from that to the verb that gave rise to it.

Comment: Teeter:  To move or sway unsteadily or unsurely; totter. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/teeter. I think OP wants to define a movement forward in one direction before the fall of the car.

Comment: I’m with you @chaslyfromUK- if a car is so precariously balanced on the edge that it will fall with the slightest change in weight distribution then it is teetering on the edge regardless whether it only goes in one direction.   Another word for a slow (but increasing) fall over the edge is simply *tipping*

Comment: Okay our dictionaries don't agree. Let's allow the OP to decide. I've added a comment requesting clarification. The OP says 'as a boat does in a storm' and that involves movement so I'm still correct.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK "To get off the axis" in one word. I think it might be what i'm looking for.

Comment: @АнтонЕршов - The phrase 'To get off the axis' doesn't convey anything to me. Perhaps you mean the car overturned?  I still don't know what the car did. Do you have a picture of a car doing this?

Comment: Okay, that car is 'tilted' I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Gracias

Comment: @АнтонЕршов - De nada.  You could say, The car stopped and started to tilt [over]. Or 'The car stopped and tilted [over].'

Comment: The CDO definition isn't good in my opinion; 'to ​sway so as to appear to be about to ​fall [while ​moving position or ​standing unsteadily]' is required. Teetering and immobility are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to [dangle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dangle):

> - To hang loosely and swing or sway to and fro. (AHD)

The car stopped and started to dangle on the edge of a cliff.

*Good Samaritan saves man dangling over cliff* - [CNN.Com](http://edition.cnn.com/2015/04/17/us/idaho-good-samaritan-rescue/):

> - 17 apr 2015 - With a truck dangling over the edge of an Idaho canyon, Jason Warnock sprang into action, ... Man trapped in car dangling off a cliff but then .

Comment: "Dangling" is more like pendulum motion. I meant a short irretrievable (one way?) action of the car.

Comment: @АнтонЕршов - sort of *sliding* off the cliff?

Comment: Something like getting off the axis a small distance. "To list" is fine if it is not applicable only for boats.

Comment: Topple: 
to fall forward, as from having too heavy a top; pitch; tumble down.
2.
to lean over or jut, as if threatening to fall.